# Youtube Analytics API- Javascript

Tags: javascript, youtube, oauth-2.0, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-analytics

I was trying out the YouTube Analytic API. On loading the webpage I am getting nothing.

The tools (Ctrl+Shift+I) provided by Chrome show me:

```
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('file://') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null').
```

I have logged into my YouTube account and I have about 3 views on a video. Why is my webpage note responding?

The link to the simple application page is given [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/sample-application#Build_HTML)

Comment: I tried to run the simple application code to no avail. Created a [Client ID](https://console.developers.google.com/project/) and stuff, but it doesn't show any oAuth... Can you outline the steps that you took to setup the app? . . . I'm trying to run from a live domain, but I see that you tried from `file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Youtube/`...

Comment: I copy pasted the code and then copied the client ID code of my application. I was already logged into youtube so I guess no oauth was needed.

Comment: @brasofilo anything you have that can help me here?